# Cannot read a public spreadsheet when signed in, but can when signed out

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets API for client-side javascript.
I cannot read a public spreadsheet when the user is signed/logged in, but can read it when the user is signed/logged out.

I adapted the quickstart guide:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

However, I purposefully do not want my app to ask for read-only permission on all the user's spreadsheets.

Since the spreadsheet is public, I can also `listMajors()` (which reads the spreadsheet) when the user is not signed in by adding a line in `updateSigninStatus`. And this works.

However, with a different set of permissions than
`var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";` , I am not able to read the spreadsheet when the user is signed in.
I would expect it would work, because anything that can be done when signed out should also work when signed in.

I use these permissions:

```js
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
```

These permissions enable me to write to the `AppFolder` and read files created by my app.

Why is my expectation wrong? Is it a bug or work as intended? Is there a scope that doesn't require more permissions that I can use to read the spreadsheet when signed in? Alternatively, can I make a request pretending I am not signed in when signed in (I don't want to sign out the user)?

Here is the full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Sheets API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '...';
      var API_KEY = '...';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest", "https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];
      // in quickstart:
      //var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
      // in quickstart:
      //var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
        // get the spreadsheet regardless of login status
        listMajors();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
       * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
       */
      function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most probably when you are signed in the application is trying to use OAuth to access the resource, and using `drive.file` to look for the file. Since the file was not created by your app, it's not finding it. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example to test this behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the full example to the post.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I have tried it with the scopes `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"` + being in the sheet and the application returned the data okay. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I am still having this issue. The application returns OK data when the user is signed out, but not when they are signed in.

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior, have you tried creating new credentials for it and maybe creating a new quickstart and changing only the scopes? Also, you can share this behavior on [Google's Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823916).

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce it. I tried with new credentials and I still hit the issue. I will share with Google's issue tracker.

Comment: I filed an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213311840

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue with even with the readonly scope. Am I correct in understanding you see the same?